# How to increase memory in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to load a 3Gb csv file in R and I getting the following warning:

Warning messages:

1: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  Reached total allocation of 7128Mb: see help(memory.size)

2: In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  Reached total allocation of 7128Mb: see help(memory.size)

I tried doing this :

> memory.size()

[1] 766.68

> memory.limit()

[1] 7128

But still my file doesn't get loaded and I keep getting this warning. Is there a way I can get around reading this file in R?

Thank you !

Comment: I've seen people suggest `fread()` in the past, might be worth looking into.
Also `gc()` might help with the error if garbage collection isn't taking place.

Comment: @zacdav.. Thank you so much :) I used         >install.packages("data.table")
>library(data.table)                                                                        >fread("file.csv",sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: The best part is it also shows the time                                                  _Read 74180464 rows and 11 (of 11) columns from 2.980 GB file in 00:08:34_

Comment: I'm glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

R can be incredibly memory inefficient when loading large datasets. From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html):

> **Memory usage**
>
> These functions can use a surprising amount of memory when reading
>   large files. There is extensive discussion in the ‘R Data
>   Import/Export’ manual, supplementing the notes here.
>
> Less memory will be used if colClasses is specified as one of the six
>   atomic vector classes. This can be particularly so when reading a
>   column that takes many distinct numeric values, as storing each
>   distinct value as a character string can take up to 14 times as much
>   memory as storing it as an integer.
>
> Using nrows, even as a mild over-estimate, will help memory usage.
>
> Using comment.char = "" will be appreciably faster than the read.table
>   default.
>
> read.table is not the right tool for reading large matrices,
>   especially those with many columns: it is designed to read data frames
>   which may have columns of very different classes. Use scan instead for
>   matrices.